# adding backgrounds to drawable already with a resource

Tags: android, xml, image, background

i have a couple image buttons in my layout one is invisible when the visible one is clicked it set its image resource to the invisible image button and sets it to visible like this

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btnmt2.setImageResource(R.drawable.happy);
            btnmt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnmt2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            btnmt2.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
```

but the visible image button has a background, (background is a shadow defined in xml as a couple of shapes) i want the image to keep this background when it is moved to the invisible one so i tried adding this in xml to no avail, the image resource seems to lose its scaling, or its padding, stretching to the full size of the background, so i tried adding it in my java file working around the deprecated methods, like this

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    btnmt2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dropshadow);
} else {
    btnmt2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dropshadow));
}
```

this keeps the scale and padding but the background isnt added, can anybody help me, not sure if its my xml image so here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="18dp" android:left="18dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="4dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a known bug where setting a View's background via a resource file can cause it to lose it's padding (need a reference link for that, though. Going to look later).

I actually use these 3 methods to get around that issue, by saving and restoring the padding before/after the image is actually loaded:

```
public static void setBackgroundResourceAndKeepPadding(View v, int resourceId) {
    int top = v.getPaddingTop();
    int left = v.getPaddingLeft();
    int right = v.getPaddingRight();
    int bottom = v.getPaddingBottom();

    v.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);
    v.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
}

public static void setBackgroundDrawableAndKeepPadding(View v, Drawable drawable) {
    int top = v.getPaddingTop();
    int left = v.getPaddingLeft();
    int right = v.getPaddingRight();
    int bottom = v.getPaddingBottom();

    setBackgroundDrawable(v, drawable);
    v.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public static void setBackgroundDrawable(View v, Drawable drawable){        
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)  v.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    else v.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

Calling either of those setBackgroundResourceAndKeepPadding() methods should circumnavigate the loss-of-padding issue you're running into.

However, this is assuming you've set the padding before setting the background image; otherwise your new padding (which seems to be 5px) is what would take over. If that's also the case, you might want to make sure that's not part of the issue you're experiencing, as 5px on a hi-res device will look almost non-existent.

Comment: sorry im a beginner ive implemented your code and is sitting there telling me the method setBackgroundResourceAndKeepPadding is never used, im having trouble declaring it where do i need to declare the method for it to apply it to the view? thank you

Comment: They're static methods that can be used from anywhere in the app at any time. Let's say they're part of a class called ViewHelper, you would then access one of them like: ViewHelper.setBackgroundResourceAndKeepPadding(v, R.drawable.icon);